# Is an injective ring morphism always a monomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, ring-homomorphism

My question is about rings. I know there exists epimorphisms that are not surjective (e.g. the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$), but I want to know if there is an equivalence (on rings, more exactly, commutative rings with unity) between monomorphisms and injective homomorphisms. If there's that equivalence, would you provide an elementary proof? Or some book where I can find them?

Comment: It is true.  You can prove it yourself, it's stupidly easy.

Comment: Hint: if $f : R \to S$ is a monomorphism of rings, and $x, y \in R$, then consider $g, h : \mathbb{Z}[t] \to R$ defined such that $g(t) = x$, $h(t) = y$.  (The role of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ here is as the free ring with one generator.)

Comment: You probably want to show the converse, that is, monomorphisms are injective, because the title has the easy implication.

Comment: Jajaja stupidly easy :)